# Libtool Discards Static Library When Building Shared Library

Tags: c++, static, shared, automake, libtool

I am trying to build a shared object for gstreamer.  I have a static library that I need to link into it.

I have tried many things, but no matter what libtool discards my shared library.

I tried:

1. `-Wl,--whole-archive ${EZSDK}/linux-devkit/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/ti/sdo/linuxutils/cmem/lib/cmem.a470MV -Wl,--no-whole-archive`
   But libtool simply removes it and shows 
   `-Wl,--whole-archive -Wl,--no-whole-archive`
2. I tried to add it to `mylib_la_LIBADD=$(EZSDK)/linux-devkit/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/ti/sdo/linuxutils/cmem/lib/cmem.a470MV` but that also did not work.  The libtool echo shows the cmem.a470MV but when it executes the link, the archive is gone.

Could anyone offer any suggestions?

Comment: Show your entire libtool invocation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by giving libtool the finger and specifying

```
-Wl,--whole-archive -Wl,${EZSDK}/linux-devkit/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/ti/sdo/linuxutils/cmem/lib/cmem.a470MV -Wl,--no-whole-archive
```

Alternatively, you can:

```
-Wl,--whole-archive,${EZSDK}/linux-devkit/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/ti/sdo/linuxutils/cmem/lib/cmem.a470M,--no-whole-archive
```